# Multiple character matching in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` query with a column with comma separated values which will also be used in a `WHERE` clause. I have tried using `LIKE`, `IN` and none of them worked.

Example:

```
SELECT ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn 
FROM ...    
WHERE CommaSeparatedColumn LIKE '%1,2%'
```

The `SELECT` is supposed to return a value if the `CommaSeparatedColumn` contains either `1` or `2`.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version and can you post test data? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you do why LIKE did not work? Read the manual. It matches the string. It looks for a string that strats with ANYTHING, then contains "1,2" then ends with ANYTHING. IN does the same as long as 1,2 are in string form as you give. THe are not comma separated, they are ONE STRING - SQL Does not care about what is in the string and how people abuse the relational database to strore lists in a string.

Comment: @TomTom The CommaSeparatedColumn was generated from a SubQuery. It was not a stored value.

Comment: That is NOT what your query says. And it does not matter - I am not sure where you get the idea that SQL cares how you generate a string of you get the semantics of LIKE wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> The SELECT is suppose to return a value if the CommaSeparatedColumn contain either 1 or 
>   2.

No, it is not. It is, as per documentation, supposed to return a column if CommaSeparatedColumn contains a string that:

- Has ANYTHING (at least 1 character)
- Followed by the string "1,2"
- Followed by ANYTHING (at least 1 character).

SQL does not care that you do not use it as relational database and store a list in a string , it does simple string matching. LIKE does EXACT matching, as per documetation, and does not care that it is either or. IN is the same, btw., - IN ('1,2') will match EXACTLY.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution (using `LIKE`) is the following statement:

```
SELECT ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '4,3,2,8'),
   (2, '1,3,2,9'),
   (3, '5,8')
) v (ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn)
WHERE 
   (CONCAT(',', CommaSeparatedColumn, ',') LIKE '%,1,%') OR
   (CONCAT(',', CommaSeparatedColumn, ',') LIKE '%,2,%')
```

Result:

```
ReferenceNumber CommaSeparatedColumn
1               4,3,2,8
2               1,3,2,9
```

An additional option is to use `STRING_SPLIT()` (for SQL Server 2016+):

```
DECLARE @match varchar(100) = '1,2'

SELECT ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '4,3,2,8'),
   (2, '1,3,2,9'),
   (3, '5,8')
) v (ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(v.CommaSeparatedColumn, ',') s1
   JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@match, ',') s2 ON s1.[value] = s2.[value]
)
```

or

```
SELECT ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn 
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '4,3,2,8'),
   (2, '1,3,2,9'),
   (3, '5,8')
) v (ReferenceNumber, CommaSeparatedColumn)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(v.CommaSeparatedColumn, ',')
   WHERE [value] IN ('1', '2')
)
```